# want to use lato light - font weight not changing

Tags: css, fonts

Want to use Lato light.. the following didn't work:

```
body {
    font-family: "lato"; 
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: 300; 
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you please post a complete code since this is not useful at all?

Comment: Did you even load the light font? Can you maybe post your html to go with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to be able to use a particular `font-weight` you first have to load it.

### Practical solution:

Replace your `<link>` tag importing **Lato** with this one:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please note the `family:Lato:300,400,700` part. Change it to suit the `font-weight` needs of your project. If you use *Latin Extended* subset, you'll also need to add it in, by changing the link to

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

You can dig deeper and serve the font files from your server but, overall, that's not recommended in terms of page speed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a lot of info to go off of, but I will say this. To change the font weight on any font you need to include to include a different a font file for each font weight. If for example you are pulling in "lato" from google fonts using this link

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

then only the default font weight (400) will be pulled in. In order to include a different font weight (such as 300) you need to add that to the link like this

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Notice now it will pull in font files for 300 and 400.

If you are using your own font files, not google fonts, you will nedd to include the font style sheet for 300 yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example which includes all weights except italic variants:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.light {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.black {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<p class="light">weight 300</p>
<p class="regular">weight 400</p>
<p class="bold">weight 700</p>
<p class="black">weight 900</p>
```